# Помощь с маршутизацией на 2 пк

Tags: windows, сеть

Есть 2 ПК. Первый ПК выступает в роли роутера, на нем раздается интернет через PPPOE на второй ПК. Но суть в том что есть так же и внутренняя сеть, по которой я получаю доступ к локальным ресурсам провайдера. Задача такова, чтобы второй ПК получал помимо интернета еще локальные ресурсы провайдера.

Как это можно организовать? Понимаю что через маршутизацию, но не могу понять как.

Настройки 1 ПК с инетом и доступом к ресурсам провайдера:

- **IP** - 10.11.7.95
- **MASK** - 255.255.255.0
- **Шлюз** - 10.11.7.1

Настройки 2 ПК куда должно раздаваться и интернет и локальные ресурсы провайдера:

- **IP** - 192.168.137.124
- **MASK** - 255.255.255.0
- **Шлюз** - 192.168.137.1

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, что у 1 компьютера 2 сетевых карты, к одной напрямую подключен интернет? К другой сетевой что подключено - 2 комп напрямую, или "локальные ресурсы" провайдера? В общем, распишите поподробнее.

Comment: Да все правильно, у 1 ПК две сетевые карты и напрямую через PPPOE заведет интернет, и штатными ресурсами, сделана раздача интернета на 2 сетевую карту для 2 ПК. Интернет идет через PPPOE а локальные ресурсы идут через просто обычную локальную сеть. С раздачей интернета ничего сложного все получилось сделать штатными средствами Windows, а вот осталась одна проблема, как еще 2 сетевой карте дать доступ к первой сетевой карте, откуда идет доступ к локальным ресурсам.

Comment: вот все равно не понятно. Подсетей две или три (внешняя, внутренняя между двумя компами и "локальные ресурсы провайдера"), на обоих компах по две сетевых карты?

Comment: Подсети две. То есть, 1 подсеть 10.11.7.1 это подсеть провайдера где размещены ресурсы. Вторая подсеть 192.168.137.1 это уже сеть между 1ПК и вторым. В 1 ПК стоит 2 сетевые карты где размешены эти два интерфейса, а во втором ПК стоит одна сетевая карта где получает вот этот IP 192.168.137.124. Получается что на 1 ПК две сетевые карты с двумя разными подсетями 10.11.7.1 (провайдер) 192.168.137.1 (сеть к 2 ПК) а на 2 пк просто 1 сетевая карта которая принимает этот ip 192.168.137.124 тем самым получает интернет от 1 ПК через раздачу PPPOE.

Comment: т.е. на 2 компе интернет есть, но подсеть 10.11.7.0 он не видит? `ping 10.11.7.1` на втором компьютере что показывает?

Comment: Да на 2 компе интернет идет, а подсеть 10.11.7.0 не видит. при пинге пишет что заданный узел не отвечает.